# Merging rows where a column has same values but other columns are different in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where a column are replicated with different values while values in the other columns are 0 or 1.

```
df

          B151452 B160128 B160363     Cytoband
A1BG            1       0       0            A
A1BG-AS1        1       0       0            A
AURKC           0       1       0            B
C19orf18        0       0       0            B
CENPBD1P1       0       1       0            B
CHMP2A          0       1       1            B
```

I want to merge rows with same values in column `Cytoband`. In other columns, 1 is kept as long as it appears once in the same `Cytoband`.

```
          B151452 B160128 B160363     Cytoband
1               1       0       0            A
2               0       1       1            B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `aggregate` with `max` as `FUN`

```
aggregate(.~ Cytoband, df, max)
```

-output

```
#   Cytoband B151452 B160128 B160363
#1        A       1       0       0
#2        B       0       1       1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(B151452 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B160128 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), B160363 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Cytoband = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1BG-AS1", "AURKC", "C19orf18", "CENPBD1P1", "CHMP2A"))
```

Comment: Thank you. What if other columns are TRUE and FALSE rather than 1 and 0?

Comment: @LinCaijin that would work as well because TRUE -> 1 and FALSE -> 0 `max(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))#
[1] 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `any` value is 1 in the column for each `Cytoband`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Cytoband) %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~+(any(.))))

# Cytoband B151452 B160128 B160363
#  <chr>      <int>   <int>   <int>
#1 A              1       0       0
#2 B              0       1       1
```